# Comonoidal categories?

Tags: category-theory, definition, monoidal-categories, categorification

Monoidal categories are everywhere. They can be defined as pseudomonoids in the monoidal bicategory $(\mathsf{Cat},\times)$ of categories, functors and natural transformations. By turning directions of arrows around, one obtains the notion of pseudocomonoid in a monoidal bicategory. Have these be studied before? Call a pseudocomonoid in the monoidal bicategory $(\mathsf{Cat},\times)$ a comonoidal category. Why are monoidal categories so prevalent, but comonoidal ones are not?

Comment: I imagine (Cartesian) comonoidal categories don't come up because every category is one in an essentially unique way, just like every set has a unique (Cartesian) comonoid structure.

Comment: Yes the notion is "boring" when $\otimes = \times$, in particular for $(\mathbf{Cat},\times)$.

Comment: In the way that a $V$-module category over a monoidal category $V$ generalises the monoidal categories, there are also $V$-comodules. And each (symmetric closed) monoidal category $V$ is a comodule over itself, suggesting that a comonoidal category might be interestingly defined as something with a bifunctor $V^{op}\times V\to V$ and some coherence isomorphisms

Comment: @MartinBrandenburg naively, there is no reason for this to be the case for $\cal{V}$-enriched categories for non-cartesian monoidal $\cal{V}$, right? So for example comonoidal additive categories might actually be interesting...

Comment: Yes I agree. The OP didn't mention enrichments though

Comment: To summarize and quote [Street and Day](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0301209.pdf): "A comonoidal category would have, instead of a tensor product, a tensor coproduct $A\rightarrow A\times A$ and a counit with appropriately coherent constraints; this concept is not so interesting for ordinary categories but becomes more so for enriched categories."